# Node.js sequelize Create an object although the association fails

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize on node.js.

My model object for Asset:

```
module.exports =
    class Asset extends Model {

        static init(sequelize) {
            return super.init(
                {
                    AssetID: {
                        field: "asset_id",
                        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                        allowNull: false,
                        primaryKey: true,
                        autoIncrement: true
                    },
                    AssetName: {
                        field: "asset_name",
                        type: DataTypes.STRING(40),
                        allowNull: false
                    },
                    SKU: {
                        field: "sku",
                        type: DataTypes.STRING(30)
                    }
                },
                Object.assign({
                    sequelize,
                    tableName: "assets",
                })
            );
        }

        static associate(models) {
            Asset.Listings = this.hasMany(models.Listing,
                 {
                     as: 'Listings',
                     foreignKey: {name: 'AssetID', field: 'asset_id'},
                     sourceKey: 'AssetID'
                 })
        }
    };
```

And the listing definition is:

```
module.exports =
    class Listing extends Model {
        static init(sequelize) {
            return super.init(
                {
                    ListingID: {
                        field: "listing_id",
                        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                        allowNull: false,
                        primaryKey: true,
                        autoIncrement: true
                    },
                    IsPreferred: {
                        field: "isPreferred",
                        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
                        allowNull: false,
                        defaultValue: false
                    },
                    Price: {
                        field: "price",
                        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE(5,2),
                        allowNull: false,
                        validate: { min: 0 }
                    },
                    ListingType: {
                        field: "listing_type",
                        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
                        allowNull: false,
                        defaultValue: "Buy",
                        validate: {
                            isIn: [['Buy', 'Rent']]
                        }
                    }
                },
                Object.assign({
                    sequelize,
                    tableName: "listings",
                })
            );
        }
```

this is my create code:

```
await Asset.create(newRecord, {include: [{ association: Asset.Listings } ]})
                .then(dbRecord => {
                    logger.debug(`New Asset created`);
                    return dbRecord;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    logger.warn(`Asset could not be created. ${JSON.stringify(newRecord)}`, err);
                    throw createServiceError(`Create Asset`, err);
                })
```

Now...my problem is that when I create a new Asset record with the listing association, in case that the creation of the listing fails (for example on the type validation, say I put "abc"), the listing will not be created (as the value is invalid) but the Asset is created.
I would expect that the entire transaction will be reverted.

It is a bit more strange because the create call ends up in the catch block.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Asaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transaction.
Sorry for formating I'm giving answer from phone.

```js
sequelize.transaction(transaction => {
Asset.create(newRecord, {include: [{ association: Asset.Listings } ], transaction})
             })
.then(function() {
    console.log('success');
  })
.catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err);
  })
})
```